# How to limits Iout from 3A to 2A using LM2576?

Tags: power-electronics

I realised that using voltage divider approach only change the Vout but Iout still remain 3A,is there any way to limit it to constant 2A with varying load resistance ?

Comment: Use a current limiter circuit.

Comment: You may consider a PTC Fuse but this simpler switcher has no current feedback input.

Comment: Why do you need to limit the Iout to 2A?

Comment: It is way easier to just use a buck converter with a 2 A current limit. Adding a current limiter circuit is possible but can get a bit complex. There are ready to use modules with an adjustable current limit, example: https://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-5V-48V-to-1-25-30V-Buck-Constant-Voltage-Current-Module-Battery-Charger-/191948534155

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LM2576 is a fixed voltage regulator, it has no possibility to limit the current by itself.

The way to go here is to build a current limiting circuit, that measured the voltage drop over a shunt resistor. If this voltage gets higher than your threshold for 2A you have to manipulate the feedback voltage of the LM2576.

Comment: @ooi-eugene: And the circuit will reduce the output voltage as required to keep the current below your limit

Comment: Couldn't you just select an inductor value to give the 2A limit?

Answer (score 0):

To limit output current, you need to have current limiter circuit as many people commented already.

use sense resistors with current sense amplifier, design the circuit for 2A and whenever the output current goes higher than 2A, current sense amplifier output should go high and that should drive LM276 IC's ON/OFF pin. That would be the easier to way to limit the current.

you can't select inductor value to limit the current. Inductor current capability is based on the peak current in the converter. If the inductor saturates for 2A output current, then that would affect your output voltage regulation.